# React Suspense: How to pass dynamic params to the fetch function outside of a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have been implementing React Suspense into my React native project.
When I navigate from the Product List Screen to the Product Detail Screen, I need to fetch data on that product. I can use id params get from useRoute hook. But React Suspense requires to call fetch outside of a functional component. So I can't get the ID of a product from useRoute hook.
How can I solve this problem?

Here are my files:

**Screen.js**

```
<Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
  <ProductDetail />
</Suspense>
```

**ProductDetail.js**

```
import axbycz...

const productData = fetch(id) //i don't know how to pass dynamic id to this function

export default ProductDetailScreen () {
  const data = productData()
  return (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let UserGeneralResource

const Users = () => {
    const { targetid } = useParams();
    if (!UserGeneralResource) {
        UserGeneralResource = SuspendableWrapper(fetch(`/api/users/${targetid}/general`).then(FetchBody))
    }
    const userinfo = UserGeneralResource.read()

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
          UserGeneralResource = null
        } 
    }, [])

    return JSON.stringify(userinfo)
}
```

Initialize the resource above the component to undefined, in your component, check if it's undefined and if so, pass in your suspendable wrapper and you can put your params in there.

You can useEffect for when the component unmounts, to reset the resource variable to undefined.